# Agrupar por variable y totalizar (sumar) algunas variables

Tags: r

En primer lugar, con las variables 
`Codcir`, `Codmun`, `Municipio` y `Mesa`
he creado la nueva variable `Código.secciones`

A continuación, necesito agrupar por esta variable `Código.secciones` el siguiente data.frame,

```
'data.frame':   1686 obs. of  29 variables:
 $ Codcir             : int  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...
 $ Codmun             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Municipio          : Factor w/ 46 levels "Abanilla","Abarán",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Mesa               : Factor w/ 820 levels "1-001 -A","1-001 -B",..: 1 2 4 5 10 224 225 227 228 232 ...
 $ Censo              : num  382 440 426 492 566 605 232 432 223 709 ...
 $ Certif..Alta       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Certif..Correc.    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Censo.Total        : num  382 440 426 492 566 605 232 432 223 709 ...
 $ Votos.Electores    : num  267 309 345 384 457 459 166 316 153 483 ...
 $ Votos.Interventores: int  2 3 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 2 ...
 $ Votos.Totales      : num  269 312 347 387 459 460 166 317 155 485 ...
 $ Votos.Nulos        : int  1 1 3 3 1 6 2 1 5 3 ...
 $ Votos.Blancos      : int  4 2 1 1 4 1 0 3 1 0 ...
 $ Cs                 : int  10 18 13 13 21 9 7 15 1 41 ...
 $ PSOE               : int  61 83 91 96 121 164 41 109 28 120 ...
 $ PACMA              : int  2 2 2 1 7 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ DPL                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ VOX                : int  52 69 98 99 102 121 36 42 38 103 ...
 $ PUM.J              : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 2 1 2 ...
 $ PODEMOS.IU         : int  12 10 13 20 13 13 3 19 10 22 ...
 $ RECORTES.CERO.GV   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PCPE               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SOMOS.REGIÓN       : int  1 1 2 4 3 0 0 1 0 2 ...
 $ PCOE               : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CONTIGO            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PP                 : int  125 124 123 144 181 145 76 120 67 189 ...
 $ MÁS.PAÍS.EQUO      : int  1 0 1 6 4 0 1 5 3 2 ...
 $ IZQP               : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Código.secciones   : chr  "3000101001" "3000101001" "3000101002" "3000101002" ...
```

Apartado i:
`Codcir`, `Codmun` y `Municipio` que toman el mismo valor para cada grupo deberían quedar asignadas a los nuevos registros de datos agrupados. La variable `Mesa` se debería incorporar como una lista para cada uno de los nuevos registros de datos agrupados (es decir, una variable que sería una lista para cada registro agrupado de los valores originales de `Mesa`).

Apartado ii:
El resto de variables son la suma de los datos originales agrupados por `Código.secciones`

Utilizdo group_by() y summarize(), pero **no sé como desarrollar el Apartado i**.

```
resultados10Nas <- group_by(resultados10N, Código.secciones)
resultados10Nas <- summarize (resultados10Nas, 
                              censo.10N = sum(Censo), 
                              certificaciones.alta.10N = sum(Certif..Alta), 
                              certificaciones.correcciones.10N = sum(Certif..Correc.),
                              censo.total.10N = sum(Censo.Total), 
                              votos.electores.10N = sum(Votos.Electores),
                              votos.interventores.10N = sum(Votos.Interventores),
                              votos.totales.10N = sum(Votos.Totales), 
                              votos.nulos.10N = sum(Votos.Nulos),
                              votos.blancos.10N = sum(Votos.Blancos), 
                              Cs.10N = sum(Cs),
                              PSOE.10N = sum(PSOE),
                              PACMA.10N = sum(PACMA),
                              DPL.10N = sum(DPL),
                              VOX.10N = sum(VOX),
                              PUM.J.10N = sum(PUM.J),
                              PODEMOS.IU.10n = sum(PODEMOS.IU),
                              RECORTES.CERO.GV.10N = sum(RECORTES.CERO.GV),
                              PCPE.10N = sum(PCPE),
                              SOMOS.REGIÓN.10N = sum(SOMOS.REGIÓN),
                              PCOE.10N = sum(PCOE),
                              CONTIGO.10N = sum(CONTIGO),
                              PP.10N = sum(PP),
                              MÁS.PAÍS.EQUO.10N = sum(MÁS.PAÍS.EQUO),
                              IZQP.10N = sum(IZQP))
```

Gracias,
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el Apartado i se refiere a lo que se llama *nesting*, o crear una especie de sub-dataframe en una de las columnas.

El uso de `nest()` del paquete `tidyr` podría ser lo que buscas.

```r
library(tidyr)

resultados10N %>%
    group_by(Codcir, Codmun, Municipio, Mesa) %>%
    nest()
```